# access template element from angular controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a html template like this

```
<div class="row form-field" ng-show="specialRequestShown" id="specialRequests">
            <div>
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="needsclick"> Non-smoking Room</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="needsclick"> Late Check-in</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="needsclick"> Early Check-in</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="needsclick"> Twin Bed</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="needsclick"> Large Bed</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="needsclick"> Extra Bed</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="needsclick"> Airport Transfer</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default gi-btn-next" ng-click="goToPayment()">
            Lanjutkan
        </button>
</div>
```

**Question:**
In the function `goToPayment()`, how can I which checkboxes checked in div `specialRequests` without having to assign `ng-model` to each one of them? Function `goToPayment()` is located in the controller. Is there anyway to loop through the div `specialRequests` children?

Comment: if you do not want to assign any ng-model you can go for ng-checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try any of these:

```
$scope.goToPayment = function () {
    var checkedItems = document.querySelectorAll('#specialRequests input:checked')
}
```

**OR**

Inject **$element** into your controller:

```
$scope.goToPayment = function () {
    var checkedItems = $element[0].querySelectorAll('input:checked')
}
```

Comment: $element is a jqlite wrapper of the dom element. $element[0] will give the native dom object, on which the method querySelectorAll is defined.

Comment: I got Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: documentProvider <- document
when using document. I have added document as dependency in the controller. Do I need to add something elsewhere?

Comment: you dont need to inject document. Document is global object available everywhere in the browser